# Correct use of commands

Tags: wpf, mvvm

So using MVVM, how do the experts handle this situation?

I have a Window with Open/Save menu items, both of which use standard WPF commanding. The Window has an underlying ViewModel containing the command objects. These command objects are instances of simple classes that implement `ICommand` internface; such as `OpenCommand` and `SaveCommand`. The Execute method of each of them calls `Open()` and `Save()` functions of the VM respectively. All the standard MVVM stuff you know!

Now the question: When user clicks Open menu item, he may already have made changes to the current document, so I'd want to check that and call `Save()` function before calling `Open()`. Who precisely is responsible for doing this and how?

1. I could do this inside the `OpenCommand.Execute()` and call `SaveCommand.Execute()` there.
2. I could call `VM.Save()` function directly inside `OpenCommand.Execute()`.
3. I could call Save() inside the Open() function of my VM too.

From the perspective of being atomic, the Open() function should really only open a document and not do other validation/checks. But then same logic applies to OpenCommand too. So where do I put this functionality?

Comment: unless you wan't disable the ability opening a new document before saving , you should call it from the Open Command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in this situation it is better to abstract of the commands, therefore I advise the third paragraph:

> I could call `Save()` inside the `Open()` function of my VM too.

---

> `Open()` function should really only open a document and not do other validation/checks.

I agree, but for example, before opening the door you should first make sure that it is closed. Does become to do a separate function? I think it will be easier and more correct:

```
private void Open()
{
    if (IsSomeChanges == true)
    {
        Save();
    }

    ...
}
```

`Command` is a [`pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) that allows you to call on the side `View` your method with minimal dependence and from different controls. If for example, you had to call the Command on the side of View, for example in the *attached* behavior, then you would need to use `SomeCommand.Execute()`. But inside in the `ViewModel` you can simply directly call this methods.